# What is SYS_OP_UNDESCEND and SYS_OP_DESCEND in Oracle Explain Plan?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have an Oracle explain plan that looks like this:

```
Plan hash value: 2484140766                                                                               
                                                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                       |   180K|    84M|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                 |                       |       |       |            |          |  
|   2 |   VIEW                         |                       |   180K|    84M|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | OSTRICH               |  6500K|   793M|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN DESCENDING| OSTRICH_ENDDATE_IDX_2 |     1 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
                                                                                                          
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                       
---------------------------------------------------                                                       
                                                                                                          
   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=180000)                                                                             
   3 - filter("OSTRICH_STATUS_ID"=2)                                                                      
   4 - access(SYS_OP_DESCEND("END_DATE")>=SYS_OP_DESCEND(SYSDATE@!))                                      
       filter(SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("END_DATE"))<=SYSDATE@!)
```

I have been trying to understand what is happening with these 2 lines at the bottom:

```
4 - access(SYS_OP_DESCEND("END_DATE")>=SYS_OP_DESCEND(SYSDATE@!))                                      
       filter(SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("END_DATE"))<=SYSDATE@!)
```

What do `SYS_OP_UNDESCEND` and `SYS_OP_DESCEND` mean?

The index that the explain plan references is (I think) called a descending index. (I do not know a lot about Oracle indexing.) The DDL for that index is:

```
CREATE INDEX
    OSTRICH_ENDDATE_IDX_2
ON
    OSTRICH
    (
        "END_DATE" DESC
    );
```

The actual query looks like this:

```
SELECT
 l.id,
 l.end_date,
 l.status
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        from OSTRICH l2
        where END_DATE <= SYSDATE
            and OSTRICH_STATUS_ID = 2
        order by l2.END_DATE
    ) l
WHERE ROWNUM <= 180000;
```

What do `SYS_OP_UNDESCEND` and `SYS_OP_DESCEND` mean? This query is taking much longer than I would expect, and I am trying to understand what impact the  descending and undescending has on the query?

Comment: is the column `END_DATE` a virtual column by any chance ?

Comment: It is not a virtual colum

Answer (score 2):

Oracle implements the descending index ["as if" it were a function-based index](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5013.htm#i2182635).  Function-based indexes are invoked when a query uses the function call; thus an FBI on `upper(col1)` would be used when the WHERE clause filters on `upper(col1) = 'WHATEVER'`.

In this case I think the SYS_OP_DESCEND is the "function" Oracle uses when creating a descending index I think it is then invoking SYS_OP_UNDESCEND because your WHERE clause is unsuited to a descending index. It's not surprising the performance sucks.

There are very few use cases where a descending index is a good idea. Why are you using one on this column on this table?

Assuming there is a good reason for using the index and you can't just drop it, your best bet for improved performance would be to not use the index for this query. Doing something like this should prevent the optimiser not using the index:

```
SELECT
 l.id,
 l.end_date,
 l.status
FROM
    (
        SELECT /*+ NO_INDEX(l2 OSTRICH_ENDDATE_IDX_2) */ 
            *
        from OSTRICH l2
        where END_DATE <= SYSDATE
            and OSTRICH_STATUS_ID = 2
        order by l2.END_DATE
    ) l
WHERE ROWNUM <= 180000;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and suggestion. I just need one clarification. What is **upper** referring to when you say `upper_col(1)`?

Comment: To answer your question about why this index is being used, I am new to this codebase, but judging by some of the other indices in the database, I don't think this is the one that was intended to be used, or at least I think I found a better index for this query. I am going to use an index hint to test if the other index will work better.

Comment: UPPER(col1) is just an example of how we would use an actual function-based index.

Comment: would you happen to know why in the bottom line of the explain plan, the row count is 1. here is the bottom line: `|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN DESCENDING| OSTRICH_ENDDATE_IDX_2 |     1 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |`

Answer (score 1):

`SYS_OP_UNDESCEND`and `SYS_OP_DESCEND` are internal functions used by the CBO that appear in the EXPLAIN PLAN when a function based index is used or a sort operation inside an index clause has been specified.

In your case, you are using an INDEX with a SORT clause

```
CREATE INDEX
    OSTRICH_ENDDATE_IDX_2
ON
    OSTRICH
    (
        "END_DATE" DESC
    );
```

Your plan shows these two operations:

- `access(SYS_OP_DESCEND("END_DATE")>=SYS_OP_DESCEND(SYSDATE@!))`
- `filter(SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("END_DATE"))<=SYSDATE@!)`

The first operation is the access, based on the desc index clause of the index itself, and the second the filter. Both appear because the query is done against the nature of the index.

I would never use this clause in any index unless the access is done in that way always, which is quite rare because sorting in different ways is what normally SQL is used for.

There is also this bug: ( fixed in 20.1 )

Bug 27589260  wrong sort order due to virtual column replacement in function based index

That degrades the performance of the query when a virtual column is present in the table and a function based index has been used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Roberto. In regards to what you said here:

"That degrades the performance of the query when a virtual column is present in the table and a function based index has been used."

I am not familiar with what you mean by function based index. Based on the index definition I gave above, is my index function based?

Comment: for this line: `filter(SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("END_DATE"))<=SYSDATE@!)`, is the CBO actually doing 2 different sorts (one descending and one ascending)?

and if so, what is it sorting? is it sorting the index or results of the query?

Comment: @fozzy_bear_waka_waka, a function based index is an index that uses a function of any type to make a calculation/transformation over the column being indexes. When you create an index with the "desc" option, it creates a index as a composite function based index.

Comment: @fozzy_bear_waka_waka, regarding your second question, it is filtering what you are asking to filter: `END_DATE <= SYSDATE` . To compare against SYSDATE, first it needs to UNDESCEND the data, the expression `SYS_OP_DESCEND("END_DATE")` is the function based index itself

Comment: do you know if it is undescending the index or the actual data?

Comment: the index. The plan shows access to the index, which is a segment the same as a table.

Comment: Thank you, Roberto! for row 4 of the table of the explain plan, where it is reporting on the `INDEX_RANGE_SCAN DESCENDING`, it says it is accessing one row. I am trying to understand why that would be one row if it is doing a scan. Does that mean it is returning the row in the index that is the beginning of the range of rows that meet the filter: `filter(SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("END_DATE"))<=SYSDATE@!)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219293/discussion-between-fozzy-bear-waka-waka-and-roberto-hernandez).

Comment: 1 row  usually means "wrong cardinality estimation" . Try to collect statistics with cascade true and block sample true, then use autotrace to get the explain plan.